# why karma is not in the path after installing?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I would like to try using karma to run some javascript unit tests. However, after installing using npm install -g karma

I typed karma, the system prompt that karma cannot be found. Do I need to add karma to the path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm guessing you're on Windows, which doesn't automatically put the folder containing your globally installed `node_modules` on your `$PATH`. You'll have to go into Windows' Advanced System settings and edit your path manually.

Comment: You might try creating a NODE_PATH system variable that points to your node_modules folder.